# Inno Setup: How to install a file after install?

Tags: java, inno-setup

I have a strange issue. In my Inno setup script I must to check JRE. If the minimum JRE is not installed, it's triggered the installer of the bundled JRE. This check is made after the files of my program have been installed in their destinations.

But I have 3 files that I must put them on JRE folder. So what is happening is that only 1 of this files is  deleted "magically" after the bundled JRE is installed.

I mean:

```
win32com.dll          -> {pf}/Java/jre7/bin
comm.jar              -> {pf}/Java/jre7/lib/ext
javax.comm.properties -> {pf}/Java/jre7/lib
```

After installing JRE, win32com.dll and comm.jar are there, but **javax.comm.properties** no.

So to prevent this, I want to install that file after installing the JRE. Is possible? Or any other suggestion?

Relevants parts of my script:

```
[Run]  
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
Filename: "{app}\jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Checking Java Runtime Environment... Please Wait...;Check:JREVerifyInstall

[Code]
#define MinJRE "1.7"

Function JREVerifyInstall:Boolean;
var
  JREVersion: string;
begin
if (RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment','CurrentVersion')) then 
  begin
  Result := RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'CurrentVersion', JREVersion);
  if Result then
      Result := CompareStr(JREVersion, '{#MinJRE}') <> 0; 
  end
else
  Result := true;

end;
```

Comment: How do you install that bundled JRE ? Are you running the `jre-7-windows-<platform>.exe` from the `[Run]` section of your script ? Are you deleting any file in your script ? Show us the relevant parts of your script, please...

Comment: At the momeent I don't have the script, but yes, I trigger the installer in the [Run] section and I check JRE with custom code. I don't delete any file.

Comment: Added code of my script.

Answer (score 3):

[Files] section gives you a "dontcopy" flag, which means you can package your files, but copy them (or run them or whatever) whenever you want from [Code] section. Like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "a.txt"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
    if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
      //This will actually extract your file to setup's temporary directory. 
      //If you don't do this, the file is skipped
      //The temporary directory is deleted after setup ends.
      ExtractTemporaryFile('a.txt');

      FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\a.txt'), 'c:\temp\a.txt', False);
    end;
end;
```

Use the "PostInstall" stage to extract your files and copy them to JRE folder.